# I get error in console after install ember-cli-content-policy

Tags: ember.js

```
vendor-suffix.js:1 [Report Only] Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-abcdefg' localhost:4200 0.0.0.0:4200".
```

i installed ember-cli-content-policy and i m trying to override default configuration  by adding

```
ENV.contentSecuityPolicy in environment.js
```

but i cannot the configuration still  default and i get the error when ever i ran the app

Comment: Do you mean `ember-cli-content-security-policy`? Can you show what exactly you are adding to `environment.js` and where?

Comment: exactly  ember-cli-content-security-policy  i have added this object to ENV.contentSecurityPolicy

Comment: What object? Can you show your code?

Comment: ENV.contentSecurityPolicy = {
    'default-src': "'none'",
    'script-src': ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
    'font-src': ["'self'"],
      'connect-src': ["'self'", ENV.APP.API_HOST],
       'img-src': ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", ENV.APP.API_HOST],
    'style-src': ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
    'media-src': ["'self'", ENV.APP.API_HOST]
  }

Comment: but problem may be from ember-cli-content-security-policy  because  i have try it on ember 3.8 i did get any error  i am working on v3.14

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug that has been reported on GitHub some weeks ago: https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-content-security-policy/issues/127

Ember-cli-content-security-policy applies a static nonce in testing environment and if used with development server. It's used to work-a-round a CSP violation triggered by default testing setup.

That nonce was always applied - even if `script-src` contains `'unsafe-inline'`. But a present nonce overrules `'unsafe-inline'` and basically disabled it.

This has been fixed in https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-content-security-policy/pull/128 but is not released yet.